# Python "TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str"

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

```
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('my.domain.com', port=80, strict=False,  
                                  timeout=10, source_address='9.9.9.9:666')
```

gives `TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str`

What am I doing wrong? I just can't see it and can't find an example.

I am trying to code a router-like simulation, using Network Address Translation, so need to add a sender address including a port number (even if I remove the port number from `source_address` above, I still get the same error).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The optional source_address parameter may be a tuple of a (host, port) to use as the source address the HTTP connection is made from. Documentation from [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection). Try to use

```
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('my.domain.com', port=80, strict=False,  
                                  timeout=10, source_address=('9.9.9.9',666))
```

Comment: I read that documentation, of course, but I don't see where you got the answer from :-) Nvm, I am just very glad to have it. Thanx